# Bluetooth Communication

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I was wondering if there are any API's available for C# to enable communication with a Bluetooth device?

Initially, I would just want to connect the bluetooth device to my computer however, my device doesn't have any pairing code so I would have to do it without pairing.

Any existing API or any Win32 dll could be useful to me?

Help Appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057220/bluetooth-in-c-which-stack-which-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [InTheHand](http://inthehand.com/Default.aspx) API to be useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

There's a bluetooth API as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), it's for C++, but I'd assume that you'd be able to use it using Pinvoke calls. This website have some code for creating a .Net wrapper for the windows mobile version of the API, but they also seems to have started work on a desktop version [here](http://www.dotnetcore.com/tutorial.aspx?ID=9). And either way, there's quite a high chance that some of the functions will have the same signature so you might be able to use the windows mobile code to get you started.