# To Develop an Application:Using Mobile Camera as a Web Cam

Tags: c#, mobile, bluetooth

I have been tasked with doing this application:

So far: I have a J2SE application which builds a bluetooth service and waits for an incoming connection.

A J2ME application which searches for the service and when a match is found, it streams images clicking continuously with the phone's camera. The J2SE app accepts the images and displays them on the desktop machine.

But according to my project specification, I need the desktop application to be developed in C#.

What I tried?

I tried to read the J2SE code line by line and reproduce the same in C#. After googling around I found that 32Feet library was a good choice. So I went ahead and read the documentation which has code samples in VB, and tried to implement it in C#. It started well with me discovering the local device successfully but eventually i got stuck in the part related to the creation of Bluetooth service.

While most of the terminology is same with ServiceRecord, UUID/GUID etc...but I have failed miserably. Moreover I tested some code which works in VB but fails in C#. Even I tried OBEX...(a small file transfer test) which worked yesterday but fails today with an exception.

Now I am contemplating of starting from scratch all over again. Can someone help me please in suggesting ways to proceed further. I mean in what tools/library/environment should i opt for. What is the best and reliable way to develop the desktop app in C# with the J2ME app already developed.

Help required please. All suggestions even small ones are welcome. I am relatively new to both Bluetooth and C#. I have some experience in Java and J2ME.

Comment: What exceptions where thrown? What didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Its sad to see that you wish to leave back those libraries you did used and spend alot worty time tinkering with it.

Rather than leaving that effort, try to resolve it. Let us know what exceptions/errors your facing with those libs.

Many experts here shall surely help you with it. Or talk to the developer of those libs for any help needed.

Hope this kind of helps [Bluetooth in C#, Which stack, Which SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057220/bluetooth-in-c-which-stack-which-sdk)