# Read data via bluetooth using c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Lecia Disto e7100i which basically measures distance and area using laser. This device has bluetooth and can be paired with windows.
I am trying to develop an wpf app that reads the mesaured data using c#

There is no sdk that comes along with the device. 
I have tried to use 32feet.Net but since there is no proper documentation I don't know where to  start.

Is there any way that I can do to solve my problem?

Comment: The documentation at http://inthehand.github.io/html/N_InTheHand_Net_Bluetooth.htm is alright.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a full response, instead its more of a guideline on how to resolve your issue:

1. Pair the device with your Computer
2. Run the included software that displays the data somehow
3. Use WireShark to analyze the traffic
4. see if it is a standard protocol type or something custom
5. understand the protocol and reimplement it using c# and [BluetoothSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/using-bluetooth)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2009/06/21/working-with-bluetooth-devices-using-c-part-1/) demo project, and the following articles after that one.

Try to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jn05CU3mxzo)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057220/bluetooth-in-c-which-stack-which-sdk) you can see a direct answer by the mantainer of 32feet, with which you can get in touch

Check also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144862/bluetooth-apis-in-windows-net) answer

Answer (score 1):

To get started, you can try:

```
var client = new BluetoothClient();
// Select the bluetooth device
var dlg = new SelectBluetoothDeviceDialog();
DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog(this);
if (result != DialogResult.OK)
{
    return;
}
BluetoothDeviceInfo device = dlg.SelectedDevice;
BluetoothAddress addr = device.DeviceAddress;
Console.WriteLine(device.DeviceName);
BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(addr, "PIN"); // set the pin here or take user input
device.SetServiceState(BluetoothService.HumanInterfaceDevice, true);
Thread.Sleep(100); // Precautionary
if (device.InstalledServices.Length == 0)
{
    // handle appropriately
}
client.Connect(addr, BluetoothService.HumanInterfaceDevice);
```

Also make sure that

- Device appears in "Bluetooth devices" in the "Control panel".
- Device is HID or change code accordingly.

Hope it helps. Cheers!